# Lumen 5.6: php artisan make:auth

Tags: lumen, laravel-artisan

```
$ php artisan make:auth
```

> Command "make:auth" is not defined.
>
> Did you mean one of these? make:migration make:seeder

I am getting this error while trying to setup the Auth Controllers. What is the way out?

Are there any repositories from where I can take these?

Comment: I just created the controllers manually for now. If there are automated ways, I would appreciate to know!

Answer (score 1):

You can't use this command with Lumen.
You have to follow [the documentation](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication). It's simplier than Laravel.
Besides, you can use [this plugin](https://github.com/flipboxstudio/lumen-generator) to improve lumen commands.

Comment: It does not seem to have ```make:auth```